# Formula to return a corresponding number for the most recent date before a certain date in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, formula

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juVsx.png)
Trying to work out a formula that will work out the consumption for me for each vehicle looking at the last od reading for that vehicle.

It seams really easy but my IT degree is failing me, have tried using INDEX , Match array formulas as well as anything else I can think of except vba so far.

Would really appreciate someones input.

I have attached a picture so that you can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are fuelling the car with the litres mentioned at the given odometer reading. This will work if the data is sorted in chronological order.

`LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B5=B6),$C$2:C5)` looks for matching value in C column based on the previous B6 value in B Column

```
=(C6-LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B5=B6),$C$2:C5))/LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B5=B6),$D$2:D5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Not the way i was trying to do it but it works.